# Converting SQL-Server SQL to DB2 SQL

Tags: sql-server, db2

```
SELECT DATENAME(mm,actualDate) AS [Month],DATENAME(yyyy,actualDate) AS [YEAR],
(
   SELECT balance FROM tbl 
   WHERE actualDate=(SELECT MIN(actualDate) FROM tbl)) AS startingbalance,
   (SELECT balance FROM tbl WHERE actualDate=(SELECT MAX(actualDate) FROM tbl)
) AS endingbalance
FROM tbl
GROUP BY DATENAME(mm,actualDate),DATENAME(yyyy,actualDate)
```

I'm running this sql command in db2 but its not working giving me error like  (mm) is not valid in the context where it is used ?

Comment: `[Month]` is an invalid identifier in SQL. If you want to quote it you need to use `"Month"`

Comment: Does DB2 support the ANSI `extract(month from ..)` and `extract(year from ...)` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE MONTHNAME and YEAR function in DB2.

Replace

> DATENAME(mm,actualDate)   => MONTHNAME(actualDate)
>
> DATENAME(YYYY,actualDate) => YEAR(actualDate)